# Controlling the random display of two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to display on each row only one black rectangle at random position on the 4 available spaces, when the user clicks the body. 
I know i must set a condition statement but I can't figure out how exactly.

This is my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/y87gjyeo/1/

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var math= Math.round(Math.random());
        $("#div").removeClass();
        $("#div").addClass("rectangle_" + math).clone().fadeIn().appendTo("#container")
    },1000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use the same `id` for different element. If you're cloning elements, use classes instead.

There's plenty of solutions for this. I'd particularly have a counter `i`. Whenever you begin a row (`i % 4 == 0`) you randomly assign the black box position between 0 and 3. Then you clone a black square if and only if its position within the row (`i % 4`) equals the random position just defined:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Lf53prx/2/

I have also done a few tweaks, like including a control to prevent multiple execution (`running` variable) and improving the order of jQuery calls (have the original element `class`less and add classes after `clone()`.

Hope this helps!

Pablo.

Comment: It works great~!  thank you for your time.I'm a complete beginner in programming :)